# Does the results indicate that the list(position) is not updated or there is something wrong with the equation?

Tags: python

I am writing a code to update a position of a ball after it being kicked at a given angle and velocity after a certain time passed. Does the results indicate that the list(position) is not updated or there is something wrong with the equation?

```
import numpy as np
    
class Ball():
    def __init__(self, theta, v):
        self.position = [0, 0] # Position at ground is (0,0)
        self.theta = 0
        self.v = 0
        
    def step(self, delta_t = .1):
        ball.position[0] = ball.v*np.cos(ball.theta)*t
        ball.position[1] = (ball.v**2*np.sin(ball.theta))/9.81
        return ball.position
        
    
    
ball = Ball(theta = 30, v = 100)

for t in range(200):
    ball.step(delta_t = 0.05)

print(f'Ball is at x={ball.position[0]:.2f}m, y={ball.position[1]:.2f}m') # Check position
```

Output =

```
Ball is at x=0.00m, y=0.00m
```

Comment: You certainly want to update `self.position` inside `Ball.step`, not refer to an outside variable `ball`. In this case it makes no functional difference because `self` *is* `ball`, but it will make a difference or outright break in other situations.

Comment: And, well, the problem is that all those calculations just amount to `0`. `0 * cos(0) * 0.05` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few bugs in your code, I've altered it to do what I believe you intend it to do below:

```
import numpy as np

class Ball():
    def __init__(self, theta, v):
        self.position = [0, 0] # Position at ground is (0,0)
        self.theta = theta
        self.v = v
        
    def step(self, delta_t = .1):
        self.position[0] = self.v*np.cos(self.theta)*delta_t
        self.position[1] = (self.v**2*np.sin(self.theta))/9.81
        return self.position
        
    
    
ball = Ball(theta = 30, v = 100)

for t in range(200):
    ball.step(delta_t = 0.05)

print(f'Ball is at x={ball.position[0]:.2f}m, y={ball.position[1]:.2f}m') # Check position
```

With the result:

```
Ball is at x=0.77m, y=-1007.17m
```

**Explanation**

First, your `__init__` method simply set `self.theta` and `self.v` to `0`, instead of setting them equal to the values provided when initialising the `ball` object.

Second, your `step` method relied upon something called `t`, instead of `delta_t` which is what you actually rely upon in your defintion of `step`.

Finally, in your `step` method, you seem to be relying on `ball.XYZ` instead of `self.XYZ`.

Correcting all of these, I believe, makes the class function as you wish it to - whether the calculation is correct, I'll leave to you to determine.

**Note**

If what you're trying to do is plot the trajectory of a ball in free fall, you should probably update `self.v` and `self.theta` with every call of `self.step()`. Currently, `self.step()` returns where the ball will be after a given interval of time from its initial condition. If you're trying to step incrementally - with every call of `self.step()`, the current `self.v` and current `self.theta` of the ball will be different after every call of `self.step()` - but your `self.step()` definition currently takes no account of this.